# Cisco asa 5505 to use internal DNS server

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, internal-dns

I have just installed and configured a ASA 5505 firewall (basic license) which has 3 VLANs (outside, trusted, untrusted) and the configuration is really basic.

Outside is for internet, trusted is for LAN computers, untrusted is for Wifi.

We have an internal server connected to trusted with a static ip of 10.5.1.2. That server runs a Bind DNS instance. The server also runs 2 VPS instances. To make it easy to access the VPS instances they are given a domain name and the DNS instance is used to supply computers of the network with the ip for those VPS instances.

I tried to add the internal server as the primary DNS server and Googles public slave DNS (8.8.4.4) as secondary:

```
mastermind(config)# dhcpd dns 10.5.1.2 8.8.4.4
address overlap with dhcp pool ip addresses
```

However that did not work. Do I need to reserve that ip so that it's not in the DHCP pool? Or am I going at this totally wrong altogether?

---

Relevant config settings:

```
ASA Version 8.4(1) 
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address dhcp 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif trusted
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.5.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan3
 no forward interface Vlan2
 nameif untrusted
 security-level 50
 ip address 10.4.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!             
interface Ethernet0/0
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 2
# Ethernet0/2 to Ethernet0/6 has identical configuration
!
interface Ethernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 3
!
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name mastermind.local
object network obj_any 
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
!
object network obj_any
 nat (trusted,outside) dynamic interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.15.166.1 1
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 trusted

dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 10.5.1.2-10.5.1.32 trusted
dhcpd enable trusted
!
dhcpd address 10.4.1.2-10.4.1.32 untrusted
dhcpd enable untrusted
!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this correctly. I guess the reasoning for this error is that if your DNS server is dynamically configured there's a chance it could lose that IP address and break DNS for the rest of your clients. I would put a static IP on the DNS server and just change the DHCP range to exclude 10.5.1.2.

Comment: Perfect. I just changed the pool to exclude the 10.5.1.2 ip, and since the server isn't using DHCP it worked. Thank you! :)